# Visual Studios snippet not showing up in snippet menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I have started writing some snippets for myself to speed up development, but I am having a slight problem. I can only use the snippets if I write out the full shortcut name and press tab twice, but it does not show up in the drop-down. From the tutorial I watched it should show up in the menu.

[image]

[image: My code snippet menu]

and the actual code behind it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>propFullOnChanged</Title>
      <Author>David</Author>
      <Description>Property with Backing Field including OnChanged</Description>
      <Shortcut>propFullOnChanged</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[private @Type$ _unknown;
        public @Type$ Unkown
        {
            get => _unknown;
            set
            {
                _unknown = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I did just find out that propfull is an existing snippet, but it still does not explain the other one not working as the name of that one is distinct from any others.

Comment: It looks like your code snippets are stored in the wrong place. It should in be in `\\user\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 20xx\\Code Snippets\\Visual C#\\My Code Snippets` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\20xx\Professional\VC#\Snippets\\1033\\Visual C#` folder (`Professional` can be another version and `1033` can be any other lang code). Your snippet is missing the definitions parts, so it will actually write `public @Type$ Unkown` in the code file.